# Parallel for loop in c++/cli

Tags: c++-cli

```
Parallel.For(<your starting value >,<End criteria for loop>, delegate(int < your variable Name>)
{
    // Your own code
});
```

Here above I am showing some sample code in C#. I want similar functionality in C++/CLI but I don't know how to use this expression: "delegate(int < your variable Name>)".

Comment: [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) with the `parallel_policy` [execution policy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t) in the upcoming C++17 standard should be able to do it.

Comment: so what's stopping you? `Parallel.For` is available in *managed* C++.

Comment: If you are on Windows/VisualStudio, try Concurrency::parallel_for

Comment: Are you looking for [OMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP)? See this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z19s8e0.aspx).

Comment: In c++ cli not supporting concurrency::parallel_for. It is throwing some errors

Comment: Choose one tag, only.

Comment: Oh wait... if you are using c++cli (which you did not mention in the question), then what's stopping you from using the same Parallel.For that you use in C#?  System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel is a regular .Net Framework class

Comment: @yms I don't know how to use this expression "delegate(int < your variable Name>) " in c++ cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using c++cli, then you should be able to use the same Parallel.For that you use in C# since System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel is a regular .Net Framework class

Example (untested, not even compiled):

```
ref class SomeClass  
{  
public:  
   static void Func(int index)  
   {  
      Console::WriteLine("Test {0}", index);  
   }  
};  

delegate void MyCallback(int index);  

int main( )   
{  
   MyCallback^ callback = gcnew MyCallback(SomeClass::Func);     
   Parallel.For(0, 9, callback);
}
```

Relevant: [How to: Define and Use Delegates in C++/CLI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c320cx3h.aspx)